# Is using one adapter (USB-c to HDMI) plugged to another adapter (HDMI to VGA) a good idea to have double screen?

Tags: adapter, usb-c, hdmi, vga, display

I have a notebook (Dell XPS 13 Developer Edition - 9350) and I am trying to connect it to an old monitor from Samsung (Model T 220, around 2009). On one hand, the monitor only has a VGA connector. On the other hand, my notebook has a USB-c port.

At the beginning of the pandemic and home office situation, I was able to have dual screens using an expensive but badly reviewed VGA to USB-c adapter. Everything was functioning.

However, the VGA-to-USB-c adapter stopped working recently. Instead of buying another VGA-to-USB-c, I decided to **try using two adapters.** I already had a functional **(I)** HDMI-to-USB-c. I just needed to buy a cheaper **(ii)** VGA-to-HDMI.

Well, I did this. After I put the two adapters together, I had: {first-adapter(VGA => HDMI)} => {second-adapter (HDMI => UBS-c)}.

The adapters  are:

- HDMI-VGA: https://www.amazon.com.br/gp/product/B076HS5TWR/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o01_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1
- Usb-c to HDMI: USB Type-C Hub Pro from FlePow | Product Model: UCN-3281

I got **some image** on my second screen. However, the quality is really bad. Far from what used to be a few days ago. It is dim/dark. It is not that half-dim problem that happens sometimes. The screen is all dark. You can read part of the stuff, but it is a hassle.

I tried changing brightness or contrast in the monitor settings. However, it was not enough to fix it.

After this experiment, I was able to do another test with a different notebook. I kept the same structure but tried with a MacBook pro from my wife. The output was exactly the same. I was able to get some image but it was fully dark/dim.

As a final experiment, I even tried using another HDMI-to-USB-c adapter which is working for other stuff. Again, the output was the same: a black and hard-to-read screen.

Hence, I started to think the problem had no relation to my pc configurations, to the monitor settings or to at least one of the adapters (I could only test changing one of them, the other was always the same in all experiments).

Maybe, this is simply not possible. So I decided to ask for help. I do not have not even superficial knowledge about VGA/HDMI/USB-c compatibility and low level stuff.

Is it possible to do what I am trying to do? Is there something that I can do to fix this? Is there any hope?

Thanks in advance.

P.S.: I am almost decided to stop being such a miserly and simply buy a new monitor. After all, 2009 is really old for tech.

Comment: “ VGA-to-USB-c adapter”. I think you meant 
USB-c to VGA... unless those digital adapters have some tuning. SOL.  FWIW on 1080 I prefer VGA cables but you don’t have this option.

Comment: At least post part numbers for the adapters.

Comment: @pjc50, sorry. I did not know this was relevant. I put the Amazon link about one of the adapters I mentioned that I bought recently and all the information I have about the other adapter.

Comment: Generally speaking, daisy chaining converters together yields poor results, as you have experienced.   It allows for higher signal degradation from the resistance the signal will encounter from each port in the chain it passes through.  Also, converters that don't have their own power supply use energy from the source port, so each device further down the chain outputs a weaker signal.  It's better to use a single direct converter. USB-C to VGA in your case.